# How to dynamically increase the field list for more items while entering data?

Tags: python, plone, ploneformgen

I use PloneFormGen to create a requirement form for a list of items.

I wish to increase the list dynamically i.e. if the items required is 2,  the number of input fields for the required items is 2. If I wish to add the 3rd item, I should be able to click a button say a "+" link and make the 3rd additional input field available to add it.

How can this feature be enabled? Is is available with plone 4.1 already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install this PFG extension: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.PFGDataGrid

"It adds a DataGridField form field to PloneFormGen.
fixed for plone 4 [vangheem]"

It should then works on PFG on Plone4.1.

Comment: Wow ...exactly what I wanted !